# Match all occurrences in a line with grep

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

How could you match all characters until first occurrence of a particular sequence of characters with `grep`? I'm looking for a way to accomplish this task in Linux environment and since I might missing some crucial point of `grep` functionality, ideas with solutions with `awk` ir `sed` are also welcome.

The problem also involves matching separately all occurrences of the pattern in a single line.

To better understand the situation, let's say we have a command
`echo "word word" | grep -o 'w.*rd'`

It looks like it matches up until last occurrence of the sequence `rd`, so when we run this we get:
`word word`

What I'm actually looking for is:

```
word
word
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do non-greedy match here, to stop at first occurrence. But since `grep` doesn't support non-greedy match by default, you can use negated character class:

```
echo "word word" | grep -o 'w[^r]*rd'
```

If you've GNU grep, then you can use `-P` option to enable Perl regex syntax. And then this would work:

```
echo "word word" | grep -Po 'w.*?rd'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-E` option in `grep` for extended regex and use `.*?` (non-greedy match):

```
echo "word word" | grep -Eo 'w.*?rd'
word
word
```

Answer (score -2):

"grep" returns every *row* that matched against the pattern you specified.

It seems that you're looking for matching the pattern per *word* and not per row.

How about breaking the input into rows of single words?
Like this, for example:

```
echo "word word" | tr -s ' '  '\n' | grep word
```